# Separate main files in SCSS result in undefined variables

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I'm basically doing a "theme" over existing scss by changing some variable definitions. I need to have separate css bundles rendered with different variables. I thought of having separate main files that import the common files to keep it DRY.

File structure

```
- variables_1.scss
- variables_2.scss
- main_1.scss
- main_2.scss
- _main-shared.scss
```

`_main-shared.scss` contains `@import` statements for all other scss files, but does not import variables.

Main file contents:

```
//main_1.scss
@use 'variables_1' as *;
@import "main-shared";


//main_2.scss
@use 'variables_2' as *;
@import "main-shared";
```

But multi-level imports do not seem to work resulting in SassError:
Undefined variable in _main-shared.scss.

Is there a better way to do this? I cannot import variables in _main-shared.scss since it would defeat the purpose of having separate variable files.

Is there a fix for this that I am not aware of or a better solution?

Comment: Why do you write `@use 'variables_2' as *;` instead of `@import "variables_2";`?

Comment: I'm also wondering why you are using both `@import` and `@use`?

Comment: @Martin - @use creates a namespace, so any variable has to be referenced as `variables.$foo`, instead of just `$foo`. `as *` imports the variables in a global namespace. It defeats the purpose of @use in sense of namespacing, but since there is a ton of places where variables are used, editing them would be too much of a hassle.

@Arkellys - Legacy. Project was using node-sass and we migrated to dart-sass. Before, @use was not used, but since it's now favoured over @import, we're migrating to @use calls. But apparently it's not a straight conversion since straight replacing gives errors